# Can we determine an $3D$ object uniquely if we know its projections from all views?

Tags: geometry

I know that it's not enough if we use its plan, front and side views only. But what if we know its projections from arbitrary views? Non-visible sharp edges and silhouette boundary will be drawed as dashed line.

Suppose we have a 3D object $M$(can be concave) and a viewpoint $\boldsymbol c$,

if $\boldsymbol x\in M$ is on a sharp edge of $M$, then we project $\boldsymbol x$ on the unit sphere surrounding $\boldsymbol c$ as a point on solid line if $\boldsymbol x$ is visible from $\boldsymbol c$, dashed line if $\boldsymbol x$ is non-visible.

If $\boldsymbol x\in M$ isn't on a sharp edge and $\boldsymbol n(\boldsymbol x)\cdot(\boldsymbol c-\boldsymbol x)=0$, where $\boldsymbol n(\boldsymbol x)$ is the normal vector at $\boldsymbol x$, then we project $\boldsymbol x$ on the unit sphere surrounding $\boldsymbol c$ as a point on solid line if $\boldsymbol x$ is visible from $\boldsymbol c$, dashed line if $\boldsymbol x$ is non-visible.

[here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJDWX.png)

The non-visible sharp edges of the cube is drawed as dashed lines.

If $\boldsymbol M$ has no sharp edges such as a sphere, then its silhouette boundary viewed from $\boldsymbol c$ , a circle, will be the projection.

[image: here is a 2D illustration]
This is a 2D illustration graph, points in red color corresponding to sharp edges in 3D case, points in blue color corresponding to silhouette boundary. And solid lines stand for visibility, dashed lines stand for invisibility.

Comment: What do you mean by "Non-visible sharp and boundary edges" and what does it mean to "draw" these?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan he is probably talking about the edges hidden behind the walls. And Andy, I think yes, if we take all the six projection using proper sign for each thing, like hidden edge and hole etc., we can do that, that's what is actually done in engineering drawings.

Comment: @ShivamSinghAswal: I have no idea what this means. If you do, maybe you can revise the question to make it meaningful, it will be closed otherwise for lack of clarity.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan @ Shivam Singh Aswal
 Thank you, and I added more detail.

Comment: Still, very unclear. What "normal" are you talking about? What if your object is not a polyhedron and has no sharp edges?

Comment: @Moishe Kohan It's the normal vector. A sphere will be projected as a circle(the silhouette boundary viewed from point c).

Comment: @MoisheKohan The vector perpendicular to the surface (assuming it's smooth there).

Comment: @Andy I think for polyhedra, at least, the answer has to be yes, since we can locate any vertex from its three views parallel to the axes and then find the edges and faces by connecting the vertices

Comment: @MoisheKohan This isn't quite a duplicate since we are drawing hidden edges. See the example image in the question, which is a 2D projection of a 3D object

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger: Of course, if a surface is smooth, then normal makes sense, but OP gives a cube as an example, making a normal vector ill-defined. But if the surface is smooth, then I have no idea what "hidden edges" mean and OP cannot define them either.

Comment: @MoisheKohan A contour curve; a curve for which the tangent plane passes through the camera

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger: Actually, we have arbitrary views available, then is it possible to determine an object uniquely?

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: we can consider the object as a collection of smooth 2D manifolds with boundary patched up; if a point x locate in the interior of some smooth 2D manifolds, then its normal is defined naturally, and be projected only when its tangent plane passed through the camera; if x locate in the boundary of some smooth 2D manifolds, then it will be projected all the time.

Comment: Author added a 2D illustration to help understanding.